# Como deletar um elemento de um vetor em C++, permanentemente

Tags: c++

Não tenho muito conhecimento do "pass-by-value" do C/C++, e também não sei muito bem quando devo passar ponteiro ou nāo a um argumento de função. A seguir é o código que tenho:

```cpp
Struct Customer {
   ....
}

int get_nearest (int n, vector<int> v) {
   ....
   v.erease(v.begin(), index);
}

int get_ticket() {
   ....
   for (Customer e : customers) {
        cout << get_nearest(e.money, prices) << "\n";
    }
}
```

O método `get_nearest(...)` chama o método `erease(...`) que eu entendo que remove um dos elementos do vetor `v`. Portanto, ao chamar `get_nearest(...)` como auxiliar no método `get_ticket()`, percebo que o vetor que passo como argumento nāo é modificado permanentemente, já que eu obtenho o seguinte resultado:

Ao chamar :

```cpp
int main() {
   vector<int> v = {5, 3, 7, 8, 5};
   get_ticket(4, v);
}
```

o output gerado é:

> Vetor: {5, 7, 8, 5}
>
> Elemento selecionado: 3
>
> Vetor {5, 3, 7, 5}
>
> Elemento selecionado: 8
>
> Vetor {5, 7, 8, 5}
>
> Elemento selecionado: 3

Contudo, na terceira iteração, onde o elemento selecionado é 3 novamente, deveria na verdade retornar -1, já que o valor 3 deveria ter sido eliminado permanentemente depois da primeira iteração.

Porque o meu vetor `prices` só está sendo alterado temporariamente, e a cada nova iteração ele volta ao seu estado inicial?

Comment: O método `vector::erase`, tal como documentado [aqui](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/#access), modifica o _contêiner_ onde foi chamado. A questão do seu código é que, ao especificar `vector<int> v` como parâmetro, você espera o vetor como valor, e não sua referência. Desse modo, uma cópia será feita mediante invocação dessa função. [Veja mais aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647348/7445826) Peça, portanto, uma **referência** ao vetor da função `get_nearest` para deletar “permanentemente” um de seus elementos, não havendo cópia.

Comment: ao usar `vector<int>& v` estou então passando o endereço do primeiro elemento do meu vetor original?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Mas para deixar mais claro que a referência é `v`, eu iria preferir formatar como `vector<int> &v`.